# Android Pagination: Using APIs with Retrofit and Gson (Crash)

Tags: android, pagination, retrofit2

I was implementing Android pagination using TMDB Movie API with Retrofit and Gson. One tab called "Top Rated movie" will show top rated movie images with pagination from TMDB API.

Log :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: me.saidur.movietune, PID: 23778
                                               java.lang.ClassCastException: me.saidur.movietune.activity.MovieTuneActivity cannot be cast to me.saidur.movietune.utils.PaginationAdapterCallback
                                                   at me.saidur.movietune.fragments.PaginationAdapter.<init>(PaginationAdapter.java:53)
                                                   at me.saidur.movietune.fragments.TopRated.onCreateView(TopRated.java:117)
```

TopRated.java fragment class file is below:

```
public class TopRated extends Fragment implements PaginationAdapterCallback {

private static final String TAG = NewRelease.class.getSimpleName();
// Inset your themoviedb.org api key
private final static String API_KEY = "...";


List<Movie> results;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.main_progress);
    errorLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.error_layout);
    btnRetry = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.error_btn_retry);
    txtError = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.error_txt_cause);
```

> adapter = new PaginationAdapter(getContext()); // Issue raises here

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage += 1;

            loadNextPage();
        }

        @Override
        public int getTotalPageCount() {
            return TOTAL_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    });

    //init service and load data
    apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    loadFirstPage();

    btnRetry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loadFirstPage();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void retryPageLoad() {
    loadNextPage();
}


private void loadFirstPage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadFirstPage: ");

   .....
   ....
}

private void loadNextPage() {
    .....
    .....
}
```

}

PaginationAdapter.java file is below:

public class PaginationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
// View Types
private static final int ITEM = 0;
private static final int LOADING = 1;
private static final int HERO = 2;

private static final String BASE_URL_IMG = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w150";

private List<Movie> movieResults;
private Context context;

private boolean isLoadingAdded = false;
private boolean retryPageLoad = false;

private PaginationAdapterCallback mCallback;

private String errorMsg;

public PaginationAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
```

> this.mCallback = (PaginationAdapterCallback)context;// Issue raises
>   here

```
    movieResults = new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<Movie> getMovies() {
    return movieResults;
}

public void setMovies(List<Movie> movieResults) {
    this.movieResults = movieResults;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
```

....................
....................
....................(more code)

I am not able to figure out the issue why crash is occurring. What can be done to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, `getContext()` method you are calling from Fragment returns Fragment's parent Activity. Then, you are trying to cast it to `PaginationAdapterCallback`. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: @KirillStarostin Thanks for your reply. Could you please share what can be done to fix the matter?

Comment: Don't cast it like this. What is `PaginationAdapterCallback` class?

Comment: Here is PaginationAdapterCallback  class:
==================================
public interface PaginationAdapterCallback {

    void retryPageLoad();
}

Comment: Okay. So does `MovieTuneActivity` correctly implement this interface?

Comment: No, in  MovieTuneActivity does not implemented this interface. I implemented this interface in TopRated.java file by overriding retryPageLoad() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
adapter = new PaginationAdapter(getContext());
```

`getContext()` called from `TopRated` Fragment actually returns an object of `MovieTuneActivity`, which, as you stated, does not implement interface `PaginationAdapterCallback`. That's why you get this exception.

Since `TopRated` Fragment implements this interface, i think what you were trying to do is:

1. In your `PaginationAdapter` class add second parameter to constructor:

   ```
   public PaginationAdapter(Context context, PaginationAdapterCallback callback) {
       this.context = context;
       this.mCallback = callback;
       movieResults = new ArrayList<>();
   }
   ```
2. In your `TopRated` Fragment, pass it's instance to adapter, since fragment implements `PaginationAdapterCallback` interface:

   ```
   adapter = new PaginationAdapter(getContext(), this);
   ```

That should do the work. Although i am not sure that storing a reference to Fragment in Adapter is a good idea.